# Apparent BufferBlock.Post/Receive/ReceiveAsync race/bug

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

*cross-posted to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tpldataflow/thread/89b3f71d-3777-4fad-9c11-50d8dc81a4a9*

I know... I'm not really using TplDataflow to its maximum potential. ATM I'm simply using `BufferBlock` as a safe queue for message passing, where producer and consumer are running at different rates. I'm seeing some strange behaviour that leaves me stumped as to how to 
proceed.

```
private BufferBlock<object> messageQueue = new BufferBlock<object>();

public void Send(object message)
{
    var accepted=messageQueue.Post(message);
    logger.Info("Send message was called qlen = {0} accepted={1}",
    messageQueue.Count,accepted);
}

public async Task<object> GetMessageAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var m = await messageQueue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        //despite messageQueue.Count>0 next line 
        //occasionally does not execute
        logger.Info("message received");
        //.......
    }
    catch(TimeoutException)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

In the code above (which is part of a 2000 line distributed solution), `Send` is being called periodically every 100ms or so. This means an item is `Post`ed to `messageQueue` at around 10 times a second. This is verified. However, occasionally it appears that `ReceiveAsync` does not complete within the timeout (i.e. the `Post` is not causing `ReceiveAsync` to complete) and `TimeoutException` is being raised after 30s. At this point, `messageQueue.Count` is in the hundreds. This is unexpected. This problem has been observed at slower rates of posting too (1 post/second) and usually happens before 1000 items have passed through the `BufferBlock`.

So, to work around this issue, I am using the following code, which works, but occasionally causes 1s latency when receiving (due to the bug above occurring)

```
    public async Task<object> GetMessageAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            object m;
            var attempts = 0;
            for (; ; )
            {
                try
                {
                    m = await messageQueue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    if (attempts >= 30) throw;
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            }

            logger.Info("message received");
            //.......
        }
        catch(TimeoutException)
        {
            //do something
        }
   }
```

This looks like a race condition in TDF to me, but I can't get to the bottom of why this doesn't occur in the other places where I use `BufferBlock` in a similar fashion. Experimentally changing from `ReceiveAsync` to `Receive` doesn't help. I haven't checked, but I imagine in isolation, the code above works perfectly. It's a pattern I've seen documented in "Introduction to TPL Dataflow" [tpldataflow.docx](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14782).

What can I do to get to the bottom of this? Are there any metrics that might help infer what's happening? If I can't create a reliable test case, what more information can I offer?

Help!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing or what your expectations are here. I definitely think you need to keep this active on the MSDN forums more than here. You've already got the attention of @StephenToub and he is definitely the guy you want looking into it.

Comment: Nope. Never got to the bottom of it. I was unable to reproduce the problem in a small, self-contained example. As I was only using BufferBlock I rolled my own async queue implementation instead. I didn't have to change any other code... I simply reimplemented the parts of the BufferBlock interface that I was using. Works a treat now, which leaves me thinking that there was something amiss, but I can't prove it. Grr.

Comment: @spendor Very interesting, oddly enough I scrapped my own async concurrent queue implementation after finding BufferBlock... now I'll have to reconsider. Thanks.

Comment: does anyone know if this is still an issue?

Comment: @EyalPerry I've used (and evangelised) dataflow for a number of other projects and never run into this problem since. Given the maturity of the product now compared to 6 years ago, I'd be very surprised if this was still an issue.

Comment: I am currently having this issue. Did anyone ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Stephen seems to think the following is the solution

> var m = await messageQueue.ReceiveAsync();
>
> instead of:
>
> var m = await messageQueue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

Can you confirm or deny this?

Comment: That didn't work out. It didn't matter which ReceiveAsync overload I chose, the result was the same. See my comment above for my resolution.